# text print with html tags saved from ckeditor to database

Tags: php, html, laravel, ckeditor

I'm using CK editor plugin in laravel it saves all text with HTML tags in the database but when I print this in view it prints with HTML tags

```
 {{$company_detail->company_description}}
```

this is saved in the database text field

```
<p><strong>Leverage agile frameworks to provide a robust synopsis for high-level overviews. Iterative approaches to corporate strategy foster </strong>collaborative thinking to further the overall value proposition. Organically grow the holistic world view of disruptive innovation via workplace diversity and empowerment. Capitalize on low hanging fruit to identify a ballpark value added activity to beta test.</p>
```

in my view it print like 
[image]

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove HTML tag in the view file using the following way:

```
{!! $company_detail->company_description !!}
```

Or

```
strip_tags($company_detail->company_description);
```

Comment: thank you, I forget that {{ }} is print value same as saved.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo strip_tags($company_detail['company_description']);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.